# How can I remove the "Install Google Play Games" prompt in apps?

Tags: google-play-games

[image]

I uninstalled the Google Play Games app on my phone to get rid of the other annoying prompt, but now I'm left with this one. Is it possible to remove the prompt shown above?

Comment: Lucky Patcher might be a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really frustrating to see that pop-up every time we play a game.
There's a solution if You've a rooted phone with Xposed installed in it.
It's a Xposed module which will stop that pop-up.
Be careful if not rooted.

Link - [No Play Games - Xposed Module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.fifsource.android.noplaygames)

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

**No**, some games as well as some apps need the Google Play Games and Google Play Services' latest version. So it may ask you to update or use to authenticate.

The entire data of the game is stored in your mobile and Google server. The game maker's server didn't store any score or data. So it needs you to install Play Services not only for this but also to use some API calls to your account info.

You cannot remove it.

Comment: What I found odd was that I did something similar in Bluestacks (disabled Google Play Games instead of uninstalling it) and it removed the prompt. But it doesn't seem to work on my phone.

Comment: Both are different. There is many difference in bs and mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I went into Androud Notifucations menu and dusabled notifications from the Google Play Store and that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not all apps depend on Google Play installation, despite asking for it. If I press Cancel when the prompt pops up, the game still loads and I'm able to play. But I can't get rid of the pop-up. It disappeared after a long while of ignoring it on other apps, but this new game just keeps asking for it. It also loads and I'm able to play.

Comment: The question is not about how to proceed loading your game despite that prompt. Instead, it asks "*Is it possible to remove the prompt shown above?*" Your answer hasn't addressed that part yet.

Answer (score -3):

Tell the game developer to correct his sign in algorithm. If the game prompts for Play Games install, the developer set it to prompt for it. It is an extra command to give to let you see this prompt.

Comment: Google Play Games isn't just for sign-in. Games might need it for other functionality, so for any given game it might be very expensive for the developer to replace that functionality.

Comment: Every developer interested in audience and using Play Games should have a fall back function to work without it.